# How to read data in Excel in Symfony2 liuggio Excel

Tags: excel, symfony, upload

Hi I am new to Symfony2 and I need to upload Excel file to MYSQL database?
Can anyone send me a example of how to do it?
Thanks you
Raki

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but we do rather like to see research effort prior to questions being asked here. If you can include in your future questions _what you've already tried_ then people will be able to guide you better.

Comment: agreed with halfer, this question should be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding: "CodePlex/PHPExcel": "1.7.7", to your composer.json file and updating.

Add a class to sit between the PHPExcel stuff and your code.  Something like:

```
namespace Cerad\ArbiterBundle\Format;

class Excel
{
    protected function createReaderForFile($fileName,$readDataOnly = true)
    {
        // Most common case
        $reader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();

        $reader->setReadDataOnly($readDataOnly);

        if ($reader->canRead($fileName)) return $reader;

        // Make sure have zip archive
        if (class_exists('ZipArchive')) 
        {
            $reader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();

            $reader->setReadDataOnly($readDataOnly);

            if ($reader->canRead($fileName)) return $reader;
        }

        // Note that csv does not actually check for a csv file
        $reader = new \PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();

        if ($reader->canRead($fileName)) return $reader;

        throw new Exception("No Reader found for $fileName");

    }
    public function load($fileName, $readDataOnly = true)
    {
        $reader = $this->createReaderForFile($fileName,$readDataOnly);

        return $reader->load($fileName);
    }
}
```

Now in your code you would have something like:

```
$excel = new Excel();
$reader = $excel->load('SomeFileName.xls');

$ws = $reader->getSheet(0);

$rows = $ws->toArray();
```

And process away.

Answer (score 1):

the example of Cerad is an option but it doesn't use that bundle and neither work with mysql,
that bundle is a simple dependency that expose services,
If you have to store data from excel to mysql,
you need first do upload file somewhere, then
read the file with the service,
$excelObj = $this->get('xls.load_xls5')->load($filename);
and then you have to read the documentation of PHPExcel

Hope it helps a little